# Get Pixels + OrderBy Most Frequent Colors

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, colors

I'm trying to calculate the optimal palette (for a gif, maximum 256 colors) of a given image, by getting all the pixels and saving in a list of `Colors`.

```
var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapSource);
bmp.Lock();

int stride = bmp.PixelWidth * 4;
int size = bmp.PixelHeight * stride;
var imgData = new byte[size];
//int index = y * stride + 4 * x; //To acess a specific pixel.

Marshal.Copy(bmp.BackBuffer, imgData, 0, imgData.Length);

bmp.Unlock();

var colorList = new List<Color>();

//I'm not sure if this is right.
for (int index = 0; index < imgData.Length - 1; index += 4)
{
    colorList.Add(Color.FromArgb(imgData[index], imgData[index + 1], 
                  imgData[index + 2], imgData[index + 3]));
}

//Here is the main problem.
var palette = colorList.Distinct().Take(255);
```

Currently, I'm able to distinct between all the colors and take only the first 255 ones. But I need to order by usage first. How can I do that?

Also, Do you guys have any other method of doing that?

Comment: As a quick idea,what about using a dictionary having as the key the color and as the value a int where you count the number of pixels of that color?

Comment: I was thinking about that, but I still needed to count the colors and update the `Dictionary` while inside the loop.

Comment: You probably want to do something like K means clustering instead of just choosing the K most common colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to order by the usage (frequency) first, consider of using `LINQ` `GroupBy` and `OrderByDescending` to group and sort your query result, and then only takes the first element among the group by using `FirstOrDefault` or `First`:

```
var result = colorList
              .GroupBy<int, int>(x => x) //grouping based on its value
              .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()) //order by most frequent values
              .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()) //take the first among the group
              .ToList(); //not necessarily put if you want to return IEnumerable
```

Comment: I believe that's it! I just needed to change to `GroupBy<Color,Color>` instead of `int` and to add a `Take(255)` before the `ToList()`.

Comment: @NickeManarin ah yes, you could try... :)

Comment: Yep, in a mostly white image, the first color was `White`. Thanks.